# Online xml file cannot be opened on Pocket PC - WM 5.0 emulator browser

Tags: xml, pocketpc, windows-mobile-5.0

I used WCF to put up xml data to be downloaded on my pocket pc - wm 5.0. I'm on testing stage so I am using usa windows mobile 5.0 pocket pc r2 emulator. Unfortunately, data wouldn't show up on the browser of the emulator. Error says, 'The file 'xxxx' cannot be opened. Either it is not signed with a trusted certificate or one of its components cannot be found...'

Please help me. I've been looking for answers for 2 months now.
Here is the screenshot of the emulator:

[image]

and here is the screenshot of the xml file:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you mentioned is launched if the OS tries to start an executable and either of the following issue occurs:

1. you are trying to run an unsigned app on a system which requires
   signed executables
2. the executable was written for a different
   processor
3. the executale references runtime library (DLL) that is not
   available or cannot be loaded

When you try to open a xml file within Internet Explorer Mobile, it should normally load. AFAIK only msxml and related DLLs are invoked and are available on the WM5 emulator.

There is one or more registry setting that may affect xml loading, but a WM5 emulator started from scratch (reset state) should work.

Can you post screen shots and the xml file?

**The problem is with the html web reference. Although a PC web browser is capable of doing some intelligent stuff and perform the right action by just parsing the first line(s) of the references file named "codes", a windows mobile device only knows what to do with files by there mime type. This Mime type is mostly de-referenced using the the extension of the file. As the file "codes" does not have an extension, the IE mobile browser does not know what to do with the file and brings an error message. If you just use a file named "codes.xml" IE mobile is able to interpret it and shows a parsed xml file.**

Comment: As I know, it should really normally run, but I don't know what is up with MS Pocket PC. Lol. If you are right, the most probable thing that occured would be the first one. Can you please help me resolve this? I already added a screenshot and the xml file.

Comment: Unfortunately you made just the file reference unreadable in the screen shot. Is it simply like "hxxp://myserver.com/myxmlfile.xml" (replace xx with tt) or something different?

Comment: yep. screenshots of what are you looking for?

Comment: How many screen shots did you publish? I mean the emulators screen.

Comment: yep. that's an emulator screenshot.

Comment: and yep, the file reference is blured. If you are interested in a solution you should post the form of the file reference.

Comment: what do you mean by the form of the file reference? if you want the url, then it's http://msi-ecs.com.ph:8090/uom/UOMws.svc/xml/codes

Comment: That was hard to get infor from you. The problem is that the file is called "codes". How should the browser know what to do with that (it is s stupid WM device). On the PC that may be different. Please try with a file named "codes.xml".

Comment: Sorry, I thought that that was confidential. Anyway, what you said could do the trick, thank you so much. But I can't find a way on how to put an extension since it isn't really a file, but a service.

Comment: The problem is that the file is called "codes". How should the browser know what to do with that (it is s stupid WM device). On the PC that may be different. Please try with a file named "codes.xml"